# MongoDB Find exact match to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I need to find a document inside my database with `findOne()` that is an exact match to an array
The array has an unknown number of arrays within it.

Example:
I already have this object stored in my database:

```
"Data": [
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""]
    ]
```

When i submit this new item and check if it already exists in the database i get the one that is already in the database (the one above)

```
"Data": [
        ["test", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "test", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""]
    ]
```

**The problem**: When i try to change anything inside the arrays, `findOne()` doesn't detect the changed values inside the arrays and always returns an incorrect match

The code that i'm using:

```
Item.findOne(
      { title: req.body.title, Data: req.body.Data },
      async (err, doc) => { 
            // Code
      }
);
```

Comment: *"When i try to change anything inside the arrays, `findOne()` doesn't detect the changed values inside the arrays and always returns an incorrect match.."* - Soo, couple of things here. **1.** `findOne()` does not **change data**, and if you are using a pattern of `find -> alter -> save` then you are really doing things very wrong already. **2** *"...always returns an incorrect match.."* - Which means what exactly? Sorry but I do not sit at your desk, so unless you include exact detail about what is **incorrect** showing what you expect and what you get instead, then we just do not understand

Comment: Also, that's outwardly a completely pointless use of the `async` keyword. You do not actually show what code is inside that block, but since it's basically marked on a "callback", then anything you expect to `await` *inside* that block simply will not in the context of "code continuation" in the manner you are probably expecting. So it seems more likely you misunderstood the concept here. Again, show the wider focus please, since your question is unclear without the explicit details that actually explain it. Which are missing of course.

Comment: @Neil Lunn The code inside the async function is not at all important. I don&#39;t want to alter the data that is already in the database. I just want to check if that exact item that I&#39;m about to add is already in the database so I don&#39;t have unneeded duplicates. The problem I&#39;m facing is when I change values for the new item, it returns me the one that is already in the database (an incorrect one and not at all a match) you can see this in the 2 code examples I provided

Comment: You missed the point. [**Edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58784078/edit). Your question is extremely unclear and is destined for closure without the necessary edits as mentioned. I also suggest you fix whatever editor/translator you are using which is causing those escaped characters in the comment you just left. Which, BTW did not explain anything. Leave comments to clarify, not just to repeat the already unclear content of your question. And no you did not provide any code samples. Just two blocks of data an a piece of pseudo-code which does nothing. Not "clear" at all.

Comment: @Neil Lunn I'm using the stackoverflow mobile app. As for the problem let's say I have a document that has `Data: [["some random string"]]` and if I submit a new item `Data: [["some other item"]]` the findOne function that I provided above returns that the item already exists by returning the document that is already in the database (the one that has some random string in it), but that is not a correct match. The contents are completely different but the function still returns the incorrect document

Comment: Please just edit the question as per the comments which are trying to help you state. Extended comments are not explaining anything, and the question is likely to be closed in it's present form. That's the help on offer here.